# The CSS styles of my theme are not applied

Tags: 7, theming

I have integrated a new theme in Drupal, and used the following content for its .info file.

```
name = my_theme         
description = A flexible, recolorable theme with many regions.
package = Core
version = VERSION
core = 7.x

stylesheets[all][] = tabcontent.css
stylesheets[all][] = styles.css
script[all][] = settab.js



settings[shortcut_module_link] = 0


; Information added by drupal.org packaging script on 2013-01-16
version = "7.19"
project = "drupal"
datestamp = "1358374870"
```

I can't get the CSS styles on my theme. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: what is your theme folder structure?

Comment: Try to clear the cache and check that css file in a browser, if it is loaded then check it has a correct path or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your folder structure, if your `styles.css` file is under the folder CSS, then you should write

`stylesheets[all][] = css/styles.css`

Always flush all the caches when you change your `.info` file.

I think you should download the [Zen](http://drupal.org/project/zen) theme and read the [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/193318). Inside the zen folder you will find a folder named STARTERKIT, it gives you and "empty" template fully customizable.